# Video converted using ffmpeg is blank after conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to convert video types to MP4 and reduce their sizes (similar to WebP and other image formats).

I downloaded a small sample from [this site](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-video-files/sample-mp4-files/) (the first one which is 1.5M).

Then I used this command based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693375/168855):

> ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/video.mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy ~/Downloads/video-result.mp4

But after conversion, when I open it in the Google Chrome, it shows nothing. It's blank. While the original video works just fine.

What do I miss here?